# QML, How to access Loader item fields from parent?

Tags: qt, qml

I have two qml files, `MyButton.qml` and `testmain.qml`
I use MyButton, as a delegate in a listview inside `testmain.qml`. MyButton has a 'text' property.
I want to read this property from outside the Loader, like in the example below.

**testmain.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.10
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.3
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

ApplicationWindow {
    id: appWindow
    Material.theme: Material.Dark
    title: qsTr("Test QML")
    visible: true

    width: 640
    height: 480

    Rectangle {
        id: myRec
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: 'grey'

        ListView{
            anchors.fill: parent
            model: 10
            delegate: Loader{
                id:myLoader
                source: "MyButton.qml"
                onLoaded: {
                    console.log("Loader loaded")
                }
            }

            Component.onCompleted: {
            console.log("Referencing loader item: " + myLoader.item.text)
        }
        }
    }
}
```

**MyButton.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.10
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.3
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

Rectangle {
    id: button
    width: 145; height: 60
    color: "blue"
    smooth: true; radius: 9
    property alias text: label.text
    border {color: "#B9C5D0"; width: 1}

    gradient: Gradient {
        GradientStop {color: "#CFF7FF"; position: 0.0}
        GradientStop {color: "#99C0E5"; position: 0.57}
        GradientStop {color: "#719FCB"; position: 0.9}
    }

    Text {
        id: label
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: "Click Me!"
        font.pointSize: 12
        color: "blue"
    }

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: console.log(text + " clicked")
    }
}
```

Right now I'm getting the following error:
`file:///D:/Windows/Documents/qmltest/QML/testmain.qml:33: ReferenceError: myLoader is not defined` I'm unsure as to what I'm doing wrong. Line 33 is where I'm trying to reference the loader's item `console.log("Referencing loader item: " + myLoader.item.text)`

Answer (score 1):

`Component.onCompleted` is emitted when the construction of the Loader is complete, and that does not imply that the component that loads the loader is this. You must do that reading on `onLoaded` signal:

```
delegate: Loader{
    id:myLoader
    source: "MyButton.qml"
    onLoaded: {
        console.log("Loader loaded")
        console.log(myLoader.item.text)
    }
}
```

Comment: In this example, you are calling `myloader.item.text` from inside `my loader`. I want to reference the text from outside the loader. I tried to write a function that would reference `myLoader.item.text` from the outside after the `onLoaded' signal was emitted. Still getting the same error. Like so: https://gist.github.com/curtwagner1984/4bb39e7ff02e5cef9d02178621cfe054

Comment: @Curtwagner1984 You have 10 Loaders since it is inside ListView. Which of these Loaders do you mean when using the id myLoader? You realize that it is illogical, in a delegate the id is local, and it does not exist outside, I think you have an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/), what do you want to do with the text? currently the objective of your code does not have anything logical.

Comment: You have a point. This doesn't really make sense. I have a model(extended from `QAbstractListModel `) on the backend which is connected to a ListView. I want to reference a specific item in that model(By index), outside of the delegate. I wasn't sure how to do it, so I hoped to reference it back from the delegate itself since the delegate has access to that item. I see now that it was not the correct approach. Do you know how can I access specific data from a model?

Comment: @Curtwagner1984 
It depends on how your model is implemented, you are going the wrong way since as you point out it has nothing to do with the view, you can show the implementation of your model.

Comment: Indeed. Here is the model: https://gist.github.com/curtwagner1984/72ac593c7acc33d3037eae0f7e298171

perhaps this warrants another question altogether.

Comment: @Curtwagner1984 okay, what data do you want to get? Do you want to get the n-row submission? if so, you could show how the DbSubmissionQObject is implemented. On the other hand, I think it deserves another question, and I have already answered the current question correctly.